# How can I open a specific sheet named after a month?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2003, localization, date-format

I have a bunch of [Month Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDmqY.png)

What is one way to open a specific one with VBA? I tried using [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808523/open-specific-sheet-according-to-current-date):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mnth As String, dte As String, mday As String

mday = Now() - Weekday(Now(), 3)

mnth = Month(mday)
dte = Day(mday)

tabstr = mnth & "-" & dte

   For Each ws In Worksheets
       If ws.Name = tabstr Then
           ws.Select
           Exit For
       End If
    Next 
End sub
```

but that's for sheet names that are named after dates formatted as `mm-dd`, e.g.  *"11-7"* or *"11-14"*.

How do I change this code so it works for sheet names that contain month names like *"May"*, *"June"*, or *"July"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To automatically bring the current month's tab to the foreground after opening a workbook, you can simply use this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets(Format(Now(), "mmmm")).Select
End Sub
```

NOTE: This will only work if the month names are in the same language than the OS.

Answer (score 1):

To get the name of the current month:

```
Sub tretdc()
    tabstr = Format(Now(), "mmmm")
    MsgBox tabstr
End Sub
```